# CheckBox value always returns true

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

The checkbox which I had set using a variable always returns the value of variable and the checkbox is always checked.
If the value is true it returns true and vice versa

```
answerOption={isCorrect:true}
<input type="checkbox" checked={(!answerOption.isCorrect) ? false : true}  onChange={this.updateAnswerChecked.bind(this)}  style="cursor:pointer;" />
updateAnswerChecked(e){
   console.log(e.target.checked);
   answerOption.isCorrect = e.target.checked
}
```

Comment: You cannot trigger a re-render like that, you need to use setState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simpler and working example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [answerOption, setAnswerOption] = useState(true); 

  const updateAnswerChecked = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setAnswerOption(e.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={updateAnswerChecked}
      checked={answerOption}
    />
  );
}
```

with your code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [answerOption, setAnswerOption] = useState({isCorrect: true);

  const updateAnswerChecked = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    setAnswerOption({isCorrect: e.target.checked});
  };

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={updateAnswerChecked}
      checked={answerOption.isCorrect}
      style={{cursor: pointer}}
    />
  );
}
```